# Proftpd on Debian ignoring umask setting

Tags: debian

### I have found a solution for my problem. This is what I did:

I added the following to my /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf:

```
<Limit SITE_CHMOD>
  DenyAll
</Limit>
```

---

I have the following problem:

When I upload files to my FTP server the umask I set is totally ignored. All files have permissions 644.

I use **Debian 5.0.3** as operating system and **proftpd 1.3.1** as ftp server. The user logging in is called *mug* and he is a local user (no virtual user). He is chrooted to the home directory

> /home/mug/

I tried the following things:

**1. set umask setting in /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf**

```
Umask 000  000
```

This should result in 777 for directories and 666 for files since directory umask is applied to 777 and file umask is applied to 666.

After that I of course restarted the proftpd to be sure that the config is reloaded.

**2. set umask for the user in /home/mug/.bashrc**

I added the following to the .bashrc for the user:

> umask 0000

After that I reloaded the .bashrc:

> source /home/mug/.bashrc

I also checked the umask setting for the user by changing to the user and using this command:

> su mug
>   umask

As result I got a umask of 0000 prompted. So this worked.

But still all my uploaded files are having 644 permissions set :(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What user is ProFTPD running as? Are all users having the same issue, or just that one?

Comment: Proftpd is running as user proftpd and group is nogroup. And this also happens when I log in with other users.

Answer (score 1):

Proftp starts with an base mode of 0666, and since umask can only take rights away, you can never reach 0777.

Answer (score 0):

Check the umask for user Proftpd and group nogroup. Since you're trying to set permissions higher than the system default, they may be restricted by their OWN umask values.

A way to check it might be to change the umask in proftpd.conf to 777; if new files show up as 000, then you know that configuration line is working.

Comment: I set the umask in proftpd.conf to 777 as you said with the same result. To change the umask for the user proftpd I changed /etc/profile (since proftpd has no home dir) and reloaded the file again via "source /etc/profile". But again: permissions are set to 644.

Comment: Okay, so it's ignoring the umask in proftpd. Hmmmm. What version of proftpd are you using? There were a bunch of umask problems with proftpd once...

Comment: I am using proftpdd 1.3.1. But I also tried vsftpd with the same result. So my guess is that this is related to Debian.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that proftpd considers a ulimit of "000" bad and won't let you do that, it should log if that's the case.